# Will Thermalright HR-22 passive heatsink fit into an Antec P183 V3 case?

Tags: desktop-computer, heatsink, silent-cooling

I'm planning a new build of an audio workstation for a recording studio. I'd like to know if it would be possible to use the Antec P183 V3 case with a Thermalright HR-22 passive heatsink. How can I know if these are compatible before buying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dimensions for the case [here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811129174) say its outer width is 8.1 inches.  The heat sink is [159mm tall](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00G7S163Y) or 6.3 inches.  The motherboard/processor I have here looks like the top of the CPU is about 3/4 inch, call it 1 inch, risers included.

So at 7.3 inches you should have plenty of room even if the processor is right in the corner where the pieces are bracketed together.